# Getting a text inside a TAG via xpath and javascript in a html document

Tags: javascript, xpath

So, I'm trying to get the text inside of a tag in a list.

Let me say I have something like

```
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
<div>text3</div>
<div>text4</div>
<div>text5</div>
<div>text6</div>
```

so, I want to get the "number" of the DIV who matchs "text4" for example, so it will return a "4".
I cant modify the html, there is no class or ID in the divs.
Maybe I can get the innerHTML of a div? But how will I put all the divs inside a vector or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use something like jQuery? It's much easier with CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of working with elements by tag name:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var html = divs[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(html);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DEJty/

Answer (score 0):

In XPath this is

```
count(//div[.='text4']/preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

Incidentally, 'text4' is not "in" any tag; it is between two tags, a start tag and an end tag. I mention this because you will find it easier to understand specifications and error messages if you learn the official vocabulary.